# VBA button: font.bold = true work / bold = false fails

Tags: vba, button, solidworks

having a button on a VBA form I'd like to toggle the appearance between bold and non-bold.

There is no problem to make it bold like this:

```
 cmd_WriteTable.Font.Bold = True
```

However when doing the opposite (cmd_WriteTable.Font.Bold = False) nothing happens - the captions is still bold.
Any idea what goes wrong or how to bypass this?

I am using SOLIDWORKS VBA, however I expect it to be identic to Excel VBA at this point

Comment: In Excel, `CommandButton1.Font.Bold = Not CommandButton1.Font.Bold` works perfectly well as a toggle function. Assigning literally `False` works too, of course. Maybe you need to force an update of the display?

Comment: You do understand that excel is not identical to VBA. They each do things to different standards. Excel for compatibility with previous versions (that predate VBA) and VBA is a wrapper around the automation libraries. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/automation-programming-reference.

Comment: your idea ... = NOT ... bold is pretty nice by the way

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it by putting the command into a separate function. Otherwise it did not work in my application. I a test form there was no problem.

```
Function unBoldButton()
cmd_WriteTable.Font.Bold = False
End Function
```